# Lucene.net highlight

Tags: c#

I'm using Lucene.NET to implement full-text retrieval. Does anyone have experience in presenting the search results with the search terms highlighted? I would like something like Google-style that shows me the results with an excerpt of the information containing the search terms highlighted.